# How to return new model return in response response?

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

In  laravel8/inertia/vue3 app creating model I set mode of the form in “add” mode and I try when new model is created return
it in responce , like :

$role = Role::create([
'name'       => $request->name,
'guard_name' => 'web',
]);

```
return back ()->with('data', [
    'role' => $role,
]);
```

But I can not get this new model on client part with code :

```
this.form.post(this.route('admin.roles.store'), {
    preserveScroll: true,
    onSuccess: (resp) => {
        console.log('resp::')
        console.log(resp)
        Toast.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'New role created!'
        })
    },
```

In browser I do not see model returned from control : https://prnt.sc/1xxhS-EOHLSh

How can I do this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood some things:

**First:** When you use `->with`, you're putting that `data` in a session flash. You're not returning it to the client. And putting the result into the flash probably isn't what you want.

```php
return back ()->with('data', [
    'role' => $role
]);
```

**Second:** If you intend to use `onSuccess` on the client side to deal with the response, you can't `return back()`. You need to send an actual response to the client in a traditional AJAX way like this:

```php
return [
   'data' => $role
];
```

**Third:** I would encourage you to avoid using `onSuccess` and returning JSON like described above, since this kind of defeats the purpose of Inertia and I believe it's provided more like an escape hatch for situations where you can't do things "the Inertia way".

Comment: What can be "the Inertia way" here without onSuccess ?

Comment: If you stay on the same page, just "return back();". Otherwise redirect to another page which will take care of showing the roles... If you want to do something like toast notifications, you can "return back()->with('toast', 'Message here')" and then handle the toast in the session on the HandleInertiaRequest middleware.

Comment: Thanks! it helped, but how can I with message to send also message_type(success/failure) ?